# Significance of `{}` in rpc declarations

Tags: proto, protobufjs

While going through the docs of protobufjs and google protobuf official guide I noticed that there is a syntax difference between rpc declarations described by both -

- Google protobuf guide -

```
    rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply)
```

- ProtobufJS guide -

```
    rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
```

Notice the difference in `{}` at the end.

What is the significance of this ? And does it lead to a different code behavior ?

### Reference -

- Google Protobuf guide - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#services
- Protobuf JS Guide - https://protobufjs.github.io/protobuf.js/#using-proto-files